# How to get data from API without jquery

Tags: javascript, api

I'm making my first web aplication with plain javascript for practice.
Although I tried to use API, such as google map API or youtube API, I couldn't find out a way to get data from them without jquery.

It would be great if you could show me some example codes and how to get data from API resources with plain Javascript.

Comment: Use an XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Fetch API, XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/) is a list of examples from [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference). You can see for yourself there is no jQuery needed in these examples.

All of them are implemented in plain Javascript.
If you are working entirely on the Google Maps API you don't need to have knowledge of jQuery.

However, basic understanding of AJAX, asynchronous behaviour of Javascript and Callbacks is required if you want to understand the code flow.